# Apex collection column 2,3,4 etc and above value not getting properly

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

Apex collection column 2,3,4 etc and above value not getting properly in the classic report, we follow the below method to solve the issue.

Comment: "we" follow the method? How many of you are there?

Comment: i am not tried, you can tried some columns  like 10 or 20 it will work i am sure.